# Sitecore 7.2 | Drawbacks of using MVC and Web Forms in the same site built with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

**Question** : Downside of using Web forms and MVC in same sitecore instance.
 **Current Situation** : We have a Sitecore 7.2 instance developed using MVC and Glass Mapper. We want to reuse existing component which is already developed in Web Forms using the same sitecore version that we are currently using. 
**What we have done so far**: To achieve this we did a small POC and were able to achieve the same. We referred below link at Git to achieve this POC We found few blogs where people have done this but always say that it may not work all the time (and not highlighted which scenarios they fail). What are the drawbacks or possible difficulties that we could face doing this ?.It will be helpful if you can highlight as For example :Workflow does not work or personalization does not work etc. 
Thanks

Comment: "We referred below link at Git to achieve this POC" where is the link?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running a Sitecore 7.2 instance with both WebForms and MVC (we actually went the other way- our old code is Webform and with a recent redeisgn we moved to MVC) and its doable, but kind of messy.

The biggest issues we've run into have been when we want to display webform and mvc content on the same page, or have the two code bases communicate in any way. Attempting to have renderings calling both webform and mvc code on the same page was disaster. Likewise trying to have webform-only pages communicate with mvc-only pages (eg. building out submenues, getting field values, etc).

In a way, what ended up happening with us was we had essentially two sites - the webforms and mvc versions - and the two never really merged well together. Our project plan was to move off of Webforms to full MVC, so we accepted this as a reality. I'm not sure how well a permanent mvc-webform crossover solution would work, to be honest.

We had some good luck using the following resources: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc

http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/Using-Web-Forms-and-MVC-in-a-Single-Solution-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

It's been messy for us, lots of time keeping pages and code apart, and we are planning on cutting out webforms completely in the near future and going full-mvc. But running both is very doable.